# How do I make iCacls grant access at the folder level so it can be inherited?

Tags: windows, authentication

Using the command:

```
iCACLS.exe \\server\serverroot\siteroot /grant:r domain\id:RX /T /C
```

I can grant access to every file within the site root folder, but the folder itself does not receive the access. The problem being any new file that gets added lacks the read access until the command is run again. What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason the folder itself does not receive the access is because I did not tell iCacls I wanted it to make the access inheritable. The command should be:

```
iCACLS.exe \\server\serverroot\siteroot /grant:r domain\id:(OI)(CI)(RX) /T /C
```

Does exactly what I need (and for predictable reasons. I like that.)

Comment: 4 years later, and you saved my day. This (OI)(CI) part is important. Without it, files get created, but not read after that. Wich was driving me crazy.